# How to change Section name on page Layout for custom object

Tags: page-layout

How can we change section name on page Layout for custom object .
I want to change the section name from Car Information  to car details

[image: Car section page Layout]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to the respective page layout and follow the below steps.

If you are using classic follow the below steps:

setup
--> build
--> create
--> Click on Objects
--> open the respective object
--> Go to the Page layouts Section and click on edit button on the respective page layout.

Lightning Navigation:

setup --> Object Manager --> click on your respective object --> click on Page Layouts --> click on edit button on the respective page layout.

And follow the below steps

1.click on gear icon which is highlighted in yellow color

[image]

2.Rename the section Name and click on Ok button then save the pagelayout

[image]